# Is it possible to do a clean reinstall of Skyrim (non-Special Edition) via Steam with DLC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I just updated my graphics driver and Skyrim won't start anymore. After disabling all mods, and manually deleting the EBN dll's, scripts, and folders, it gets as far as the company splash screen before abruptly crashing. Before attempting to figure out how to roll back my NVidia driver (never having done so before and not having any idea what the previous verison was), I want to try a clean reinstall of Skyrim.

I have Skyrim (regular, non special edition) via Steam, along with all the DLC's except the high res graphics pack -- which I also purchased via Steam. In order to promote the Special Edition, Bethesda removed the original edition's DLC's from the Steam store. If I back up my saves, uninstall Skyrim, and reinstall it, will I lose/not be able to reinstall the DLC's since they're no longer available?

Comment: As long as the content wasn't removed from Steam it would still be available for download to those who already own it, just not able to be purchased by those who don't. That being said Skyrim may be a special case because of them upgrading users to SE from normal + all DLC (though that was temporary and has ended AFAIK). You may have better luck on Reddit or etc in a Skyrim-specific forum finding someone with experience, but it's still possible someone here may know.

Comment: The original edition DLC still isn't for sale on Steam, so it doesn't seem to be too temporary. My concern is that if I uninstall the game, that when I attempt to reinstall it the DLC won't be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have purchased the DLC for Skyrim, it should be associated with your account and should still be accessible even if you reinstall. You should be able to see a small table of the DLC you have for Skyrim and whether they're installed on the game library page. You can check this to make sure when you reinstall Skyrim that the DLC are successfully reinstalled

Answer (score 1):

You own these DLC's. In the worst case scenario - if they cannot be installed through Steam - you can [create a support ticket](https://support.steampowered.com/newticket.php).

The DLC's of the original Skyrim still exist in the Steam database, however. [Here](https://store.steampowered.com/app/220760/The_Elder_Scrolls_V_Skyrim__Hearthfire/)'s Hearthfire, [here](https://store.steampowered.com/app/211720/The_Elder_Scrolls_V_Skyrim__Dawnguard/)'s Dawnguard, and [here](https://store.steampowered.com/app/226880/The_Elder_Scrolls_V_Skyrim__Dragonborn/)'s the Dragonborn DLC.